# How does Rabb.it stream broswer windows for users

Tags: linux, vps, vnc

I am just wondering how rabbit is able to give each user a diffent  broswer to use from a linux machine it seems like vnc tech but I dont know please let me know if you know how they are able to do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a somewhat detailed blog post about what their architecture was here: https://bloggeek.me/rabbit-webrtc-interview/

I will quote the relevant part for longevity:

> We have two main stacks, one for audio/video and one for our business
>   logic:
>
> [image: rabb.it architecture overview]
>
> Our audio/video stack is built in Java on top of Netty:
>
> Our SFU allows us to use WebRTC with much larger groups than the
>   normal use case. For our shared viewing feature (called Rabbitcast™),
>   we had to build a native extension to capture and delivery an HD
>   stream with audio from our virtual machines. Both of them use our own
>   WebRTC server stack to talk to the clients. Our Business Logic stack
>   is built on top of Node.js using a promise-based approach to keep our
>   sanity.
>
> Lastly we use Redis both for intelligent caching and pub/sub. MongoDB
>   is our persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what exactly they are using but I have some ideas how it works yeah as you already said they are using virtual machines that ported to a html5 vnc client to control and stream video and audio. Other options might be using xpra,x2go,apache guacamole to port them into a html5 client again.